# GPU usage utility

Tags: amd-graphics, gpu

I'm trying to see how much my GPU is being used on my AMD iGPU, I tried Radeontop but this didn't work so I'm wondering if there's any utility that can show me GPU usage on an 4900hs.
(radeontop didn't work because it said it was maxed out but I wasn't doing anything but it did show vram).

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Pop_os 20.10 which is ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I use this one with the open source driver: https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl
Don't know if it works with your card...